# Simplecart.js Check if Simplecart_Items has items

Tags: javascript, simplecart

Is it possible to check if div class simplecart_items has items in it, like this way?

```
if(simplecart_items == 0){
    NO ITEMS IN THE CART // Shows no add to cart, no total cost and no products quantity
}
else {
    The "normal" output // Shows add to cart, total costs and products
}
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way in V3 of the simplecartjs script,

```
if(simpleCart.items().length == 0)
{
//No items in the cart
}
```

If you want to check a particular item already present in the cart, using jQuery.

```
simpleCart.bind('beforeAdd', function (item) {
  if (simpleCart.has(item)) 
  {
      alert("Already in the Cart");
      return false;
  }
});
```